# Mapping through array in React web app returning 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a component which pulls from an API and sets state from its response data.

I'm then attempting to map through the state hook and pull various details from each entry.

But for some reason, it's returning undefined each time.

Here's my component:

```
const Balance = () => {

  const [transactions, setTransactions] = useState({})

  useEffect(async () => {

    axios.get("/api/plaid/getTransactions")
    .then((response) => {
      setTransactions(response.data.transactions)
    })

  }, [])

  return (
    <div>

      { transactions.map((result, index) => (
        <p key={index}></p>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Can someone point out where I'm going wrong here? It shouldn't be returning undefined.. And the data is definitely legit as I've console logged it and it's all as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your state to this: `const [transactions, setTransactions] = useState([])`.
Otherwise you will try to map through an empty object (`{}`) on the first render. And map cannot be applied directly to an object. `[]` will make it map through an empty array on first render, and then once your axios call populates the state with, presumably, another array, it will show your results.

A slightly more user-friendly solution would actually be to set your initial state to `null` thus letting your users know it's loading. That way you can check to see if any results have been loaded yet. Once the axios call returns the results, the loading div will be replaced by your data.

```
   const [transactions, setTransactions] = useState(null);
...
   <div>
      {transactions ? (
        transactions.map((result, index) => <p key={index}></p>)
      ) : (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      )}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening due to the state `transaction` is not an array.

There are two possible solution

Firstly, instead of assigning initial `transactions` as `{}` object, we can assign it as an array `[]`

```
const [transactions, setTransactions] = useState({})
```

You can use

```
const [transactions, setTransactions] = useState([])
```

This will not generate the `undefined` error.

Another approach is optional chaining using `?.` in the `map`

Instead of direct access of `transactions`

```
{transactions.map((result, index) => (
    <p key={index}></p>
 ))}
```

With optional chaining

```
{transactions?.map((result, index) => (
    <p key={index}></p>
 ))}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should add `transactions` as a dependency to your `useEffect` since you are using state

```
useEffect(() => {
    // your code
  }, [transactions]);
```

Comment: This is incorrect. This will cause useEffect to re-render continuously.